# Compiling sqlite-devel or libsqlite3-dev?

Tags: scrapy

I receive 'No module named _sqlite3' when attempting a Scrapy script.  If I understand correctly, I need either sqlite-devel or libsqlite3-dev.

However, I don't see how to compile either.  I see apt-get and such, but I'd like to compile.

Comment: I should mention I've compiled sqlite-autoconf-3240000.  But I see no configure options to compile development.  I've also found no source code for sqlite-devel or libsqlite3-dev.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. If you are not using sqlite3 in your project.

You can simply comment on the imports from *sqlite3/**init**.py* (You can find it in the site-packages).